# How to SELECT a portion of the text in the name of a column to use COUNT() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

In the column of "name", there are a bunch of the bus station names (starting station name / ending station name. For example, they look like "LaSalle / Crawford"), and I was asked to find the most popular bus starting station. I have tried using REGEXP or LIKE, however, MySQL is not recognizing the symbol of "/" and returned no value at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I was asked to find the most popular bus starting station

You can use `substring_index()` to extract the starting station. Then, you can aggregate by that, sort and limit:

```
select substring_index(mycol, ' / ', 1) starting_station
from mytable
group by starting_station
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I have tried using this, but when I entered the query, the answer was saying I was missing a subquery. So I don't think I can write the query like that.

Comment: @moz: please run the query exactly as provided. If it errors, please share the exact, entire error message.

Comment: I mean the query works in SQL, but when I submitted through the online portal for my school, it's telling me to use a subquery to write this out.

Comment: @NIA: I have no idea how your teacher wants you to solve this. But as far as concerns, this solution is a 100% correct way to do it in MySQL...